# Flashing a Firmware

Tags: device-firmware

I was thinking for flashing a firmware through Odin. I downloaded the firmware off sammobile but when I started extracting the file winrar said it was corrupted but it finished extracting anyways. So should I go ahead and flash the firmware or should I redownload it? Sorry for such a noob question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend not to flash the firmware with a file from a corrupted archive. It could brick your phone. Maybe this is SamMobile's way of persuading you to become a premium member in order to use their fast download feature. Even without the fast download feature it would be possible to check the file integrity using the checksum of the download if one was available, but SamMobile does not provide the checksums of firmware downloads on their website.